# What's the difference between type 'a list' and type List<int>

Tags: f#

I'm new to F# and I seem to be having an issue getting the sum of a list.

```
let listOne = [1 .. 10]
let listTwo = listOne.Select(fun i -> i * 2).ToList()
let result = List.sum listTwo

result.Dump()
```

However, the following code produces this error:

```
This expression was expected to have type     'a list     but here has type     List<int>
```

Any insight as to why they are different would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F# integer lists aren't `List<T>` (i.e. `List<int>`).

This is why it throws such error: `List<T>` isn't a `FSharpList<T>`

When you call `IEnumerable<T>.Select` you're converting `FSharpList<int>` into `IEnumerable<int>`, then `IEnumerable<T>.ToList()` returns a `List<int>`.

Furthermore, you should use `IEnumerable<T>.Sum(...)`:

```
let result = listTwo.Sum();
```

Also, you won't need to convert the `IEnumerable<int>` into `List<int>`: `.Sum(...)` is a member of `IEnumerable<T>` interface.

Comment: Thanks for the well explained answer

Answer (score 1):

```
let listOne = [1 .. 10] 
let listTwo = listOne.Select(fun i -> i * 2).ToList()
```

```
listOne : int list (alias for Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List<int>)
listTwo : System.Collections.Generic.List<int>
```

As you can see, listOne and listTwo have totally different types.

Answer (score 0):

Like already posted the Problem is that F# has its own List-Type which supports all the pipelining stuff etc.

To convert a .NET-List or IEnumerable that you get by the use of Linq into a F#-List you can use **`List.ofSeq`** or **`List.ofArray`** like the following:

```
let listOne = [1 .. 10]
let listTwo = listOne.Select(fun i -> i * 2).ToList()
let result  = List.sum (List.ofSeq listTwo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Matias Fidemraizer explained the problem nicely, but it's possible to resolve your problem more idiomatically in F#, without using Linq at all.  Instead of `Select` and `ToList`, use the F# `map` function in the `List` module:

```
let listOne = [1 .. 10]
let listTwo = List.map (fun i -> i * 2) listOne
let result = List.sum listTwo
```

You could also do this all in one go, using the pipe operator:

```
let result = [1 .. 10] |> List.map (fun i -> i * 2) |> List.sum
```

You can also use partial function application instead of the `fun` keyword:

```
let result = [1 .. 10] |> List.map ((*) 2) |> List.sum
```

You can also use the sumBy function and save yourself from creating a second list in memory:

```
let result = [1 .. 10] |> List.sumBy ((*) 2)
```